# Google Maps API - infowindow on hover showing same text

Tags: api, google-maps

I have the following code setup to display a custom Google Maps interface.  I want to have infowindow on hover for each marker, with dynamic text for each pulled from the array (first position).  For some reason this code results in each marker displaying the same text, which ends up being only the first word of the final element in the locations array.

I don't understand what I'm doing wrong as the other dynamic elements from the array change each time through the loop, and get set correctly.

```
    var locations_parks = [


     ['Mahoney Park', 45.39928, -75.74984, 1, '', 'parks/mahoney.png'],    
     ['Clare Gardens Park', 45.38800, -75.74689, 1, '', 'parks/clare-gardens.png'],    
     ['Iona Park', 45.42153, -75.69719, 1, '', 'parks/iona.png'],    
     ['Parkdale Park', 45.40198, -75.72986, 1, '', 'parks/parkdale.png'],    
     ['Champlain Park', 45.42153, -75.69719, 1, '', 'parks/champlain.png'],    
     ['Lions Park', 45.39417, -75.75269, 1, '', 'parks/lion.png'],    
     ['Fisher Park', 45.39573, -75.73047, 1, '', 'parks/fisher.png'],    
     ['McCormick Park', 45.40281, -75.72716, 1, '', 'parks/mccormick.png'],    
     ['Hintonburg Park', 45.39906, -75.72019, 1, '', 'parks/hintonburg.png'],    
     ['Riverside Terrace Park', 45.39982, -75.75279, 1, '', 'parks/riverside-terrace.png'],    
     ['Plouffe Park', 45.40680, -75.71397, 1, '', 'parks/plouffe.png'],
     ['Laroche Park', 45.42153, -75.69719, 1, '', 'parks/laroche.png'],
     ['Base Marker', 45.402169, -75.726418, 1, 'Base', 'well_icon.png']

];




var markersArray = [];
var iconBase = 'http://www.doamin.com/_icons/';
var mapOptions = {

      center: new google.maps.LatLng(45.402169, -75.726418),
      zoom: 15,
      scrollwheel: false,
      scaleControl: false,
      mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    };

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map-canvas"), mapOptions);


function initialize() {


    //var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

    var marker, i;

    for (i = 0; i < locations_parks.length; i++) {  


      var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: locations_parks[i][0]
      });


      if (locations_parks[i][4] == "Base") {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_parks[i][1], locations_parks[i][2]),
                map: map
                ,icon: iconBase + locations_parks[i][5]
                ,url: locations_parks[i][4]
                ,zIndex:900
              });
      } else {
              marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations_parks[i][1], locations_parks[i][2]),
                map: map
                ,icon: iconBase + locations_parks[i][5]
                ,url: locations_parks[i][4]
                ,animation: google.maps.Animation.DROP
                ,zIndex:100
              });
      } 

      markersArray.push(marker);

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            infowindow.open(map,this);
       });

      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
            infowindow.close();
       });


    }


  }


  google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closure issue. You have to make closure for `infowindow` around event listeners, like:

```
    (function(infowindow) {

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseover', function() {
            infowindow.open(map, this);
        });

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'mouseout', function() {
            infowindow.close();
        });
    })(infowindow);
```

Comment: Thanks this worked.  Any idea why only the first word in some titles (first array position) is showing?  Should the infowindow automatically expand it's width to accommodate?

Comment: I noticed it not only with your example. A lot of time it happens only with the first one infowindow. I don't know why.